# Auth0 hosting in China

Tags: auth0, great-firewall-of-china

I am planning to use Auth0 service for Chinese users. I noticed that there are no servers that are hosted in China, and because of that my main concern is the firewall that China has. Weather my azure hosting web application will be able to access Auth0 in Australia.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#code-samples

I have a server that is in China and was able to call Auth0 api, but I am not sure how reliable that is. As the authentication and authorisation is so critical that the system I am building will stop working once the app can't access the service. Has anyone done the same integration especially for China and can share their experience?

Comment: I'm building a service that use Auth0 to authorize users in China too. Do you have any good solutions for this?

Comment: @zixia no.. but I think with my project - we are just going to do it and rely on auth0...

Comment: me too. Thanks for reply me. Are you doing an OpenSource project? mine is https://github.com/Chatie/app

Answer (score 2):

The great firewall of China has blocked many CDN providers such as AWS CloudFront/S3, Google PageSpeed, Cloudflare, etc, causing an outage for some users in the China region. Auth0 uses AWS servers so China may restrict access. It is previously been reported that `cdn.auth0.com` fails to load in China.

If you use the [Lock library](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11) as the login widget from Auth0 CDN, there are workarounds for this.

Lock library references two files:

- Client configuration files (JS files that have information about connections enabled for the application, application metadata, etc)
- Language files (For Lock Internationalisation)

You would need to change the location where Lock fetches these files using the [clientBaseUrl](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#configurationbaseurl-string-)  and [languageBaseUrl](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#languagebaseurl-string-)  options. Note that any change made to an application configuration means updating the mirror file in your server too.